# Python read file - pass variable name

Tags: python, variables, readfile, python-2.x

Very simple question for Python 2:

I am calling specific library/function passing filename with readonly flag:

```
myfunction(r'/tmp/file.txt')
```

I wanted to replace it with variable:

```
filename = '/tmp/file.txt'
myfunction(r????)
```

How can I call that function?

Comment: Any reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 2):

That is not readonly flag. That means raw string. You use it when you don't want escape sequences inside string to be interpreted (like \n, \t etc.) See https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

For your string, you don't need it since it does not contain any escape sequence. Just omit the leading r.

Answer (score -1):

```
filename = r'/tmp/file.txt'
myfunction(filename)
```

Comment: a little explanation would be nice.

Answer (score -2):

in most cases you can use

```
myfunction(r''+filename)
```

if you don't want to define the r prefix in your variable. This works with b'' and u'' too.

Comment: This does exactly nothing.

Comment: This is only another way if you don't want to define the r prefix in your variable. It does all it has to do.

Comment: You don't understand the question. Please read the linked question. `r'somestring'` is not `'rsomestring'`.

Comment: and `r'' + any_string == any_string` exactly.

Comment: Yes. But the question was r?????. And ????? stands for the variable abd how to connec. r and ????? Si i answered the question and not if r????? is ??????

Comment: You don't understand the question and your answer is not only wrong but *literally* does nothing at all. The OP was asking how to turn a string into a "readonly string" which isn't a thing. He was using the syntax for a raw string literal, but that doesn't make any more sense than a readonly string. The fact that you think it does just means that you need to go read the linked question!! :-)